# Need Help parsing stream data from php socket server with perl

Tags: perl, parsing, sockets, stream, iostream

I'm working on a project for my company that uses a socket server (php) to gather data from a remote device.  How can I make this perl program run directly on the stream instead of first having the server write to a tmp file then running this script on that file then writing out a csv file for insertion into a database?

<del>I thought about using IO::Socket but I'm not sure how to go about it.</del>

Also, If anyone has any tips/pointers on how to clean up this code it would be appreciated. (I'm still very much a Perl n00b ;-))

Here's what I have so far for the perl prog.( I wind up with two tmp files after this is run):

```
#vim set sw=2 ts=2
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
&convert;

#open the source file, strip out any unneeded chars, reformat the data
sub convert{
    my $source = "$ARGV[0]";
    my $dest = "$ARGV[0]"."_tmp.txt";
    chomp $source;
    open SOURCE, '', $dest or die "Could not open '$dest' $!";

    # move the data from the source file into an array
    my %fields;
    my @field_names = qw/FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4 FIELD5 FIELD6/;
    my $pack_definition = 'a4 a2 a1 a4 a4 a8A*'; 
    while(){

        # strip out the packet header 
        s#T18##g;
        s#T00##g;
        s/^(FF14).*$//g;
        s/^(FF18).*$//g;
        s/(^|\n)[\n\s]*/$1/g;

        # arrange the data into the necessary order
        @fields{@field_names} = unpack($pack_definition, $_);
        s#(FF15)(.{2})(.{1})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})#$1\t$2\t$3\t$5$4\t$7$6\t$11$10$9$8#g;
        s#(FF16)(.{2})(.{1})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})#$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t$6\t$7\t$8\t$9\t$10\t$11#g;
        s#(FF17)(.{2})(.{1})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{4})#$1\t$2\t$3\t$5$4\t$7$6\t$8\t$9#g;
        my @spds =  /(FF15)\t(.{2})\t(.{1})\t(.{4})\t(.{4})\t(.{8})/;

        # convert the data from hex to ascii
        foreach my $data (@spds){
            my $replacement = hex($data);  
            s#$data#$replacement#g;
        }
        my @psis = /(FF16)\t(.{2})\t(.{1})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})\t(.{2})/;
        foreach my $data1(@psis){
            my $replacement1 = hex($data1);
            s#$data1#$replacement1#g;
        }
        my @rates=  /(FF17)\t(.{2})\t(.{1})\t(.{4})\t(.{1,4})\t(.{4})\t(.{4})/;
        foreach my $data2 (@rates){
            my $replacement2 = hex($data2);  
            s#$data2#$replacement2#g;
        }

        # print the converted data to the destination file
        print DEST;
    }
    # close the files
    close SOURCE;
    close DEST;
}
&create_vals;

# perform conversion from raw values to human readable output
sub create_vals{      
    my $source = "$ARGV[0]"."_tmp.txt";
    my $dest = "$ARGV[0]"."_converted.txt";
    chomp $source;
    open SOURCE, '', $dest or die "Cannot open '$dest' for writing $!";
    while(){
        s#(65301)\t(.{2})\t(8)\t(.{1,5})\t(.{1,5})\t(.{1,4})#"'".$1."','". $2."','". $3."','". ($4/8)."','". ($5/8)."','". ($6/20)."'"#eg;
        s#(65302)\t(.{2})\t(8)\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})\t(.{1,3})#"'".$1."','". $2."','". $3."','". $4."','". (($5*1.8)-40)."','". (($6*1.8)-40)."','". ($7*.58)."','".($8*.58)."','".($9*.29008)."','".(($10*1.8)-40)."','".$11."'"#eg;
        s#(65303)\t(.{2})\t(8)\t(.{1,5})\t(.{1,5})\t(.{1,5})\t(.{1,5})#"'".$1."','". $2."','". $3."','". ($4*0.014)."','". ($5*.05)."'"#eg;
        print DEST;
    }
}
    close SOURCE;
    close DEST;
__END__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "run directly on the stream" means "accept connections from a remote device instead of the PHP server" then IO::Socket is a way to go. Google has [plenty of examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=TCP+Servers+with+IO%3A%3ASocket) and you can also check out [perlipc](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/pod/perlipc.pod#TCP_Servers_with_IO::Socket) documentation.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the server app separate. What I was thinking of was if there's a way to run this on the data with out having to write so many temp files (i.e. Data comes into server -> server writes data to blah.txt -> perl program opens blah.txt runs &convert then writes that data to blah_tmp.txt -> then runs &create_vals and writes data to -> blah_converted.txt.) If I could just keep it contained so that it runs on the data before the server writes it to the temp file then writes that data to the db that would be great.

Comment: If you are able to modify the server app, then you could try calling a Perl script from within PHP as described in http://devzone.zend.com/article/1712.

Another approach could be passing the data to your Perl script via a pipe, another socket, a database, etc. 

BTW, in your existing chain of transformations you can probably do without  blah_tmp.txt unless you _need_ to save it.

Comment: awesome.....thanks for the info.  I'll give those a try as soon as I get a chance...